# Using LISTAGG function in SQL causes error: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, listagg

I was trying to used the `LISTAGG` function in SQL and I facing the following error:

> Invalid operation: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit Details: 
> ----------- error: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit code: 8 ...

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Use smaller strings?  The error is quite clear.  Please explain how you want to handle the data that is too big.

Comment: Please post the code causing the error message. In addition, since the error is related to the amount of data passed into `LISTAGG`, some sample data or a description of the data you're working with would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer to ListAgg functio documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html

The return data type is varchar(max) that is 64K varchar size

The error you described is exactly mentioned in the official documentation

You can think of using ListAgg() function with Distinct as follows to reduce the items to be concatenated

```
select listagg(distinct sellerid, ', ') within group (order by sellerid) from sales
where eventid = 4337;
```

Comment: this is working well if you have duplicated values. so with use of distinct will solve. But what about the time, we don't have the duplication and distinct in this case won't work. what should we do in this case?

Comment: @MaryamPashmi I've added the solution for that, please refer to this answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68831944/6194097

Comment: In my case, I cannot use distinct. How can I simply trunk the list?

Answer (score 7):

This is the reason for the issue we encountered.

[image]

---

Here is the SQL query I tried to execute,

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "year_level", LISTAGG("value", ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "year_level") OVER (PARTITION BY "year_level")
FROM "school_1__acara_db"."acara_data_set";
```

and this is the error I got.

```sql
ERROR: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit code: 8001 context: LISTAGG limit: 65535 query: 4360256 location: string_ops.cpp:116 process: query1_127_4360256 [pid=1793] -----------------------------------------------
```

[image]

---

Let's break this issue into small segments. So as they mentioned I've exceeded the maximum limit of `LISTAGG`. We can find it with the below SQL query which values are exceeded in the `"value"` column according to the `"year_level"`.

```sql
SELECT "year_level", SUM(OCTET_LENGTH("value")) as total_bytes
FROM "school_1__acara_db"."acara_data_set"
GROUP BY "year_level"
ORDER BY total_bytes;
```

This is the output.

[image]

[OCTET_LENGTH](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OCTET_LENGTH.html) returns the length of the string in bytes(octets).

As you can see values related to the `Primary Ungraded` have total bytes of `50329` and `Secondary Ungraded` have `61178` bytes. Both aren't exceeding the `VARCHAR(MAX)`, the `65535` limit. At least can I get `LISTAGG` values for the above two records? This is the query I'm going to execute,

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "year_level", LISTAGG("value", ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "year_level") OVER (PARTITION BY "year_level")
FROM "school_1__acara_db"."acara_data_set"
WHERE "year_level" IN ('Primary Ungraded', 'Secondary Ungraded');
```

I got the same error, `Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit Detail: -----------`. As we can see in the above result it didn't exceed the `VARCHAR(MAX)`, the `65535` limit. But why? Let's see the `"value"` column count related to the `"year_level"` with the below query.

```sql
SELECT "year_level", COUNT("value") as total_counts
FROM "school_1__acara_db"."acara_data_set"
GROUP BY "year_level"
ORDER BY total_counts;
```

This is the output.

[image]

Before moving to the further explanation, let's see how `LISTAGG` works.

---

In Redshift, `LISTAGG` can be used as an [Aggregate function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html) or a [Window function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html) and it transforms data from multiple rows into a single list of values separated by a specified delimiter. For the below example, the delimiter is `,`  (comma with spaces).

The following image is taken from the [Oracle's Listagg Function - Uses and Duplicate Removal](https://www.slideshare.net/BryanMack/oralces-listagg-function-uses-and-duplicate-removal) article and it is related to the Oracle, but can get the basic concepts of the `LISTAGG` function.

[image]

That is how the data is merged with the delimiter.

---

Even our query also used the delimiter as `,`  (comma with spaces). Let's get the first record in the below image as an example.

[image]

`"Primary Ungraded"` has `3412` records consist of `50329` of total bytes. So this means we are going to merge `3412` records into a single column. When we merge it should have `50329` of total bytes. But we are not merging directly, we are merging with the delimiter. So there are `3411` delimiters in-between `3412` records.

```py
delimiter_count = no_of_records - 1
```

If not understand please check the `Example #1` image of how data is merged. So according to this when we run our last failed query without a delimiter, it should work.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "year_level", LISTAGG("value", '')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "year_level") OVER (PARTITION BY "year_level")
FROM "school_1__acara_db"."acara_data_set"
WHERE "year_level" IN ('Primary Ungraded', 'Secondary Ungraded')
```

[image]

Yes, it's working fine. But this won't work for other records, because without doing anything they already exceeded the `VARCHAR(MAX)`, the `65535` limit.

---

A lot of people suggest using the `DISTINCT` keyword with the `LISTAGG` function. Both [Aggregate function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html) and [Window function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html) support `DISTINCT` keyword as an optional.

[Aggregate function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html)

```sql
LISTAGG( [DISTINCT] aggregate_expression [, 'delimiter' ] ) 
[ WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_list) ]
```

[image]

[Window function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html)

```sql
LISTAGG( [DISTINCT] expression [, 'delimiter' ] ) 
[ WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_list) ] 
OVER ( [PARTITION BY partition_expression] )
```

[image]

Without duplication, I have data which are exceeding the `VARCHAR(MAX)`, the `65535` limit. So I can't use it in my case.

---

Can't we slice the data into smaller parts? Yes, we can do it with the below query, don't be confused and the below solution was found by one of my teammates' name Isuru.

```sql
SELECT year_level, num_of_parts, listagg(value,',') AS listagg_data FROM (
    SELECT year_level, value, total_bytes / 60000 AS num_of_parts FROM (
        SELECT year_level, value, SUM(OCTET_LENGTH(value)) OVER (PARTION BY year_level ORDER BY value ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS total_bytes
            FROM "school_1__acara_db"."acara_data_set"
        )
)
GROUP BY year_level, num_of_parts
ORDER BY year_level, num_of_parts;
```

This is the output.

[image]

Using this you can grab all the information you want. Here we are slicing the `total_bytes` by `60000` and can see how many pieces were broken in the `num_of_parts` column. `'Primary Ungraded'` didn't slice into any part and  'Secondary Ungraded' has been sliced into 2 parts as we investigated earlier likewise it has been sliced into multiple parts by `60000`.

The issue we encountered is a database limitation. So programmatically we can merge the `LISTAGG` values into a single place. At the moment I don't see any other solution or couldn't find any proper solution throughout the internet.

Comment: Thank you Isuru Mahesh for your valuable time to put in this issue. Again thank you so much.